# Chrome Dev Tools - Mobile Web emulator is too small

Tags: google-chrome, emulation

Sometimes when I load a mobile web emulator the site appears tiny, and sometimes it looks perfectly normal. It's driving me insane trying to figure out why this happens.

Here's an [example screenshot of a correctly displayed page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gfDF.png) on the inspector page and here's a [screenshot of an incorrectly displayed page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KNi3.png). As you can see on the second screenshot the page appears to be tiny.

Any idea of why this is happening or how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd say your question is not quite clear: first you describe the issue as "sometimes this and sometimes that", but you also attached screenshots with not very clear description yet with distinct difference: if I understand correctly, the first one is for the page put to your web hosting and the second one is for localhost. Please do clarify this and ask an explicit question. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks YakovL. The issue is that the size of the pages in the emulator is vastly different, why? Yes, that's correct the first is a page that's hosted and the second is on local host.

Comment: So, the size is small on localhost only and always?

Comment: No, there instances when hosted sites look small in the emulator as well. I'm not sure if it is a settings within chrome dev tools I am missing (which I googled) or something else fairly silly that I am missing.

Comment: Ok, so this has nothing to do with localhost/web? In this case your description was somewhat misleading. Check out an edit that I've proposed.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a page which a) you saw in both correct and incorrect ways and b) which won't get changed so that guys can try it multiple times? Also, was your browser full screen in both cases?

Comment: Thanks YakovL. I do not have an example other than my local host. But as soon as I do, I'll add it to this thread. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 14):

I think your problem is missing viewport meta tag.
Put this in the head section of your page and it should be good.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```